# set the element's property to a default value in "from" keyword of keyframes rule

Tags: javascript, html, css

By using the **from** and **to** keywords of the **keyframes** rule the animation is declared by specifying the needed property of the element in question. However, the **from** keyword seems to be expecting an element's property with a predefined value - I have tried **auto**, **inherit**, **initial**, etc. with no avail. The problem is that I want to move an element down by specifying **top**, but I don't know the initial value (possible to achieve with **js**, but I'm hoping there's a different solution).

Here are the 2 fiddles:

http://jsfiddle.net/v4m92/

and

http://jsfiddle.net/hExdU/

```
@keyframes kf {
    from {
        top: 0;
    }
    to {
        top: 10px;
    }
}
```

The difference lies merely in giving **top** a predefined value - as it can be seen the animation works only in 1 of the examples. Is there something that can be done to make the other one work without figuring out the dimensions with javascript and modifying the underlying animation rule?

Comment: How about using `transform: translateY(XX)` instead of `top`? This way the initial value of `top` is irrelevant http://jsfiddle.net/hExdU/1/ may not suit your needs though.

Answer (score 0):

like 2rror404 suggested, you could use CSS transform to accomplish the same thing.

```
@keyframes kf {
    from {
        transform: translateY(0);
   }
    to {
        transform: translateY(100px);
    }
}
```

(shown without browser prefixes for brevity)